# How can I get windows to release an IPv6 address

Tags: windows-7, networking, ipv6

I have a windows system with an IPv4 address and an IPv6 address and I'm trying to figure out how to release my IPv6 address.

I've tried `ipconfig /release6` and I get this error

```
An error occurred while releasing interface Local Area Connection : The system cannot find the file specified.

An error occurred while releasing interface Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1 : The system cannot find the file specified.

No operation can be performed on isatap.{6B874193-B28A-4446-B6E6-8ADAC22E5090} while it has its media disconnected.
No operation can be performed on IP6Tunnel while it has its media disconnected.
```

I still have my IPv6 address at the end.  I can release IPv4 address using `ipconfig /release`

- the command prompt *is* running elevated
- the IPv6 address *was* assigned by DHCP

Comment: You could try just unchecking the IPV6 checkbox in the properties of your network adapter.

Comment: Seems like your command prompt is not elevated, thus the errors. Moreover, you can only release addresses assigned by DHCP, are you sure your IPv6 address is assigned in this way (most are auto-configured and not assigned via DHCP).

Comment: It might be useful to post the output of an ipconfig /all.

Comment: This is why I hate Windows: cryptic confusing error messages, and *NOONE* has any freakin' idea what is *ACTUALLY* going on, not even Microsoft (imagine a car manufacturer asking you to whack random parts of the engine with a hammer because it "might" work).

"The system cannot find the file specified.": what file?  Where did I specify a file?  And why doesn't it *find* this mysterious file?  If I knew the answer to the first question (apparently even MS doesn't know or won't tell) I might get a better idea what is actually going on.

SHEESH.

Answer (score 2):

Powershell with Administrator Rights

Try delete IP6Tunnel
`netsh interface ipv6 delete interface IP6Tunnel`

or

Show ip addres: `netsh interface ipv6 show address`
Delete ip/use Interface name: `netsh interface ipv6 delete address Ethernet0 200x:x:x:x:x:x:x:x`
netsh interface ipv6 delete address (Interface index or name) (ipv6address)

Show routes: `netsh interface ipv6 show route`
Delete route: `netsh interface ipv6 route delete 200x:x:x:x::/64 Ethernet0 store=persistent`
netsh interface ipv6 route delete (ipv6prefix::/64) (Interface Index or Name)

Answer (score 2):

```
ipconfig /release6  
ipconfig /renew6
```

Comment: The OP indicates this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

A completely powershell way to do this is:

```
Get-NetAdapter
```

...locate the ifIndex number of the adapter you wish to modify.  Then verify the IPv6 address you wish to release is on that interface index number.

```
Get-NetIPAddress -ifIndex *number* | where-object {$_.PrefixOrigin -notlike "WellKnown" -and $_.AddressFamily -like "IPv6"}
```

If you want to get rid of all non-well-known IPv6 addresses (i.e. addresses other than fe80::) ...

```
Get-NetIPAddress -ifIndex *number* | where-object {$_.PrefixOrigin -notlike "WellKnown" -and $_.AddressFamily -like "IPv6"} | Remove-NetIPAddress
```

..then answer yes .. or add -Confirm:$False to the end to not prompt for confirmation.